# How can I use Lambda to convert a String array to Integer array?

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8

I am trying to use lambda expressions to convert a String array to an Integer array.

I have provided my code below, along with a brief description of what I have tried so far:

```
String [] inputData = userInput.split("\\s+");
Integer [] toSort = new Integer [] {};
try {
    toSort = Arrays.asList(inputData).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
}catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Error. Invalid input!\n" + e.getMessage());
}
```

The lamba expression I have above is one which maps to an int array, which is not what I want, upon compiling this code I get the following error message:

```
BubbleSort.java:13: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to Integer[]
            toSort = Arrays.asList(inputData).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseIn
t).toArray();

          ^
1 error
```

Is there a simple way which allows me to use lambdas, or other means, to get from a String array to an Integer array?

Comment: just use a for loop ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already pointed out by others, `mapToInt` returns an `IntStream` whose `toArray` method will return `int[]` rather than `Integer[]`. Besides that, there are some other things to improve:

```
Integer [] toSort = new Integer [] {};
```

is an unnecessarily complicated way to initialized an array. Use either

```
Integer[] toSort = {};
```

or

```
Integer[] toSort = new Integer[0];
```

but you should not initialize it at all, if you are going to overwrite it anyway. If you want to have a fallback value for the exceptional case, do the assignment inside the exception handler:

```
String[] inputData = userInput.split("\\s+");
Integer[] toSort;
try {
    toSort = Arrays.stream(inputData).map(Integer::parseInt).toArray(Integer[]::new);
}catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Error. Invalid input!\n" + e.getMessage());
    toSort=new Integer[0];
}
```

Further, note that you don’t need the `String[]` array in your case:

```
Integer[] toSort;
try {
    toSort = Pattern.compile("\\s+").splitAsStream(userInput)
        .map(Integer::parseInt).toArray(Integer[]::new);
}catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Error. Invalid input!\n" + e.getMessage());
    toSort=new Integer[0];
}
```

`Pattern` refers to [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) which is the same class which `String.split` uses internally.

Comment: But if you don’t mind sort an `int[]` instead of `Integer[]`, you could just live with the result of `.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()` and change the type of `toSort` to `int[]`.

Answer (score 6):

`mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()` returns `int[]` array since `matToInt` produces `IntStream` but `int[]` array can't be used by `Integer[]` reference (boxing works only on primitive types, which arrays are not).

What you could use is

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
//...
toSort = Stream.of(inputData)
               .map(Integer::valueOf) //value of returns Integer, parseInt returns int
               .toArray(Integer[]::new); // to specify type of returned array
```

Comment: This has returned an error on the variable `Stream`: `BubbleSort.java:13: error: cannot find symbol ... symbol:   variable Stream` Is there something I need to import for this method to work?

Comment: @JamesZafar Yes, you need to add import to `java.util.stream.Stream;`. You should probably start using IDE which will allow you to add imports automatically.

Comment: or `IntStream.boxed()`

Comment: @bayou.io that is not such bad idea as I though at start, since `.Integer::valueOf` will first need to parse String to `int` and then boxes it to Integer. But I still prefer `.map(Integer::valueOf)` since it feels easier.

Comment: @bayou.io: sure, but it would be a bit nonsensical to use `mapToInt` just to be followed by `boxed()` when you can use `map` in the first place.

Comment: @Pshemo: it doesn’t matter whether you use `.map(Integer::valueOf)` or `.map(Integer::parseInt)`; both will first parse to an `int` and then wrap it to an `Integer`. The only thing that matters is whether you use `map` or `mapToInt`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an `Integer` array, don't map to an `IntStream`, map to a `Stream<Integer>` :

```
toSort = Arrays.asList(inputData).stream().map(Integer::valueOf).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Comment: This returns anotherBubbleSort.java:13: error: incompatible types: Object[] cannot be converted to I
nteger[] error for me, similar to the first one: `BubbleSort.java:13: error: incompatible types: Object[] cannot be converted to I
nteger[]`

Comment: @JamesZafar Sorry. I used the wrong `toArray` method. Fixed now.